# self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO not working when view controllers are swapped out

Tags: ios, ios6

I'm experiencing some weird behavior with hiding and showing the UINavigationBar.

In my `viewWillAppear` method I'm calling this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

and when the user presses a button I'm calling this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
```

and then swapping out the current view controller using the viewControllers property of a custom UINavigationController.

This works fine, but if I try to show the navigationBar using the same line in the `viewWillDisappear` method, it doesn't work. The navigationBar is still hidden.

I'm able to show/hide the status bar in `viewWillDisappear` using the following method:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

but showing/hiding the UINavigationBar doesn't work!

EDIT: Also, `self.navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden` returns `NO` after I try to show the bar in `viewWillDisappear` but the bar is still hidden.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What exactly are you referring to by "swapping"?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. I meant in my subclass of UINavigationController I have a method that changes the view controllers. Like this: `self.viewControllers = @[viewController1];` where viewController1 is the new controller I want visible on the screen to replace the current view controller.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because you’ve already swapped the current view controller out of the stack, `self.navigationController` is probably `nil` when `viewWillDisappear` is called.

Comment: That was stupid of me. You were right, swapping out the controllers made `self.navigationController` nil. All I had to do was keep a reference to self.navigationController and then call `self.myLocalNavigationControllerReference.navigationBar.hidden = NO;` in viewWillDisappear to show the navigation bar again. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're better off not messaging `self.navigationController` from `viewWillDisappear` as eager pointed out since it may be `nil`.  Rather than holding on to a reference, I recommend editing the `navigationBarHidden` property always from within `viewWillAppear` as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27748007/2248638 .  I have a `BOOL navigationBarHidden` property on my `UIViewController` base class so that I only need to set the property once for those view controllers which are hidden.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:self.navigationBarHidden animated:animated];
}
```

Comment: Not a fan of setting it on each view controller. If you have to disable it in one single view controller, it forces you to revert it all other view controllers in the stack, unless you make assumptions about navigation order, which isn't good.