# Push / Pop View Controller With Navigation Bar from View Controller Without Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to push a view controller with a visible navigation bar from a view controller with a hidden navigation bar.

I tried all sorts of combinations of `[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];` in viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, viewWillDisappear... etc.

```
// First View Controller

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

    NSLog(@"[%@ viewWillAppear]", self);
}

@end


// Second View Controller


@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];

    NSLog(@"[%@ viewWillAppear]", self);
}

@end
```

Nothing worked. I also tried custom code to "animate" a push and pop, which works, BUT I lose the edge swipe and view panning. Before I dig deeper, just want to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel.

The Starbucks app is what I'm trying to mimic.

The root view controller of the app (the dark background view) is full screen and notice how it doesn't have a UINavigationBar. But when you tap on one of the buttons, it pushes on a view controller (the light background view) WITH a UINavigationBar. From there, if you tap the "back" arrow, it view controller pops with the navigation bar. Interactive pop swipe gesture also works.

[image: Starbucks iOS App]

Comment: Is the only reason for having the navigation bar showing in in the 2nd view so that there is a back button? Or are other things (aside from the title/subtitle) that you need the navigation bar for?

Comment: Definitely need the back button, but also need a functional navigation controller/bar as the user drilled deeper.

Comment: Ahh got it. I was going to say you could just add a custom view to the top with a back button that calls popViewControllerAnimated and keep the nav bar hidden. I suppose you still could, but I don't know how complex things get as you drill deeper

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is -- you mention code to hide the navigation bar, but not code to actually push the next controller. Are you calling pushViewController:animated:?

Comment: If you want to swipe without the auto implemented back feature, add this to your VC.  I usually drop it in viewDidLoad: `self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;`

Comment: @rdelmar i am using pushViewController. the issue is the UINavigationBar does not follow the pushed view controller. It just appears above.

Comment: @Logan if I implement the interactivePopGestureRecognizer delegate, can I animate the UINavigationBar frame so it "pop/push"  with the view controller?

Comment: Hmm, not sure, I don't think it will do that automatically though.

Comment: Yeah... Seems like that is the case.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is possible without hacking together a solution by yourself. Here is what you do:

Your root viewController:

```
@implementation ViewController

....

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}

@end
```

And the pushed viewController:

```
@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
}

@end
```

This will do. It also keeps the interactive transition working ;)

I find it disturbing, however, that this type of functionality is not documented at all by apple. - You can also hide and show toolbars with these 'call-points' (inside viewWillAppear:)

**EDIT**

I just realized that this is the same code you wrote in your question. Please test it again. I am 100% sure that this works - I used this functionality in one of my apps, too.

Please also note that my code does use `animated:animated` instead of your `animated:NO`. This may be the crucial point here :)

Comment: "Please also note that my code does use animated:animated instead of your animated:NO. This may be the crucial point here :)"  indeed it was the crucial point. Thanks!

Comment: Passing the `animated` BOOL was the kicker for me. Simply passing YES/NO caused some weird navigation bar behavior when I performed the interactive (drag back) pop animation.

Comment: If you store a `BOOL navigationBarHidden` property on your `UIViewController` base class, then you only need to set the property to `YES` for viewControllers which hide it, and override `viewWillAppear` to call `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:self.navigationBarHidden animated:animated];`

Answer (score 1):

I just set up two view controllers to test this back and forth.

```
@interface VC1 ()

@end

@implementation VC1

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}

@end
```

and a second

```
#import "ViewControllerTwo.h"

@interface ViewControllerTwo ()

@end

@implementation ViewControllerTwo

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}

@end
```

VC1 is embedded in a navigationController (which is the root controller for the app), with a button that navigates to ViewControllerTwo. I have a push segue from VC1 -> ViewControllerTwo, this method works. When I tap on the button, the view controller is visible on ViewControllerTwo, when I press back, the navigationBar is gone.

Comment: that was also what I did first, but creative won't let that fly. if you swipe from the left to pop the view controller, the navigation bar disappears immediately, instead of following the view controller.

Comment: So for clarification, the problem isn't that you can't get rid of the navigation bar, it's that you want the navigationBar to animate alongside the ViewController your popping so that they stick together, correct?

Comment: Correct. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I recommend one of two approaches. Either create your own navigation bar boxes as part of the View controller, and trigger pop and push from the UINavigationController programmatically (easiest way if you're still early in development), or, a more complex but robust route would be to take a look at custom view controller transitions.