# Navigation Bar move up while pop animation of Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

In my root view, I create a navigation controller and add it 20 px below the status bar.

**My Navigation View controller**

The status bar appears normal.

[image]

**When I click Back,** (Freezed Animation for screenshot).

The view moves up when the animation is happening. And
 After it completes, the status bar appears back.

[image]

**Code: This is how I add the navigation controller to my VC**

In RootView:

```
navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:myView];

navController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
navController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
    CGRect frame=navController.view.frame;

    frame.origin.y += 20;
    frame.size.height-=20;
    navController.view.frame=frame;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer helped me a lot.

[Push / Pop View Controller With Navigation Bar from View Controller Without Navigation Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369046/push-pop-view-controller-with-navigation-bar-from-view-controller-without-navi)

I add my navigation controller with first VC, and it wants the navigation bar hidden

I had it as `animated:NO` in below snippet.. The correct usage has to be using the animation `boolean` from the delegate itself.

**In VC1: The Navigation Bar should be hidden**

I have to hide the navigation bar like below.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // Hide the bar with animation how viewWillAppear is called
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}
```

When I push VC2 to VC1, I need to enable the navigation bar back. So in VC1 itself, during the disappear iI do the below.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    // Show the bar with animation how viewWillDisappear is called
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
}
```

**In VC2: The Navigation Bar should be shown**

When I press back in VC2, I actually have to hide the navigation bar again. So, I do it in viewWillDisappear.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    // Hide the bar with animation how viewWillAppear is called
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}
```

> The Main key is `animated:animated` and not `animated:NO` ..
>   Unbelievable.!

Answer (score 1):

So I believe this is your problem

```
frame.origin.y += 20;
frame.size.height-=20;
navController.view.frame=frame;
```

It has been called every time your view load. I believe if you go forward and backward many times the view is going up on your window. is it? If yes. Make sure that will be called just once.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks. It made sense, but no it is called only once.