# Weird animation when hiding the navigation bar

Tags: ios, animation, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uipageviewcontroller

I'm implementing a photo gallery via a UIPageViewController subclass (called GalleryController) embedded in a UINavigationController. The navigation bar hides when I tap, but the animation is odd:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SLF3Nq3uNE

Here's the code in GalleryController:

```
  override var navigationItem: UINavigationItem {
    let item = super.navigationItem
    // Access super and add items to it.
    // Don't create a new UINavigationItem instance — that breaks the back button.

    let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    space.width = touchSize / 2

    item.rightBarButtonItems = [
      UIBarButtonItem(title: "All Photos", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(showAllPhotos)),
      space,
      UIBarButtonItem(title: "Delete", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(deletePhoto))
    ]
    return item
  }
```

This problem started occuring only after the page view controller was introduced.

What's causing this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: but your code is not related to hide animation

Comment: I experienced similar (but not the same) issue, and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369046/push-pop-view-controller-with-navigation-bar-from-view-controller-without-navi) worked. Check your viewWillAppear(). override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {;super.viewWillAppear(animated);navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated);self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true;}

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik The hide animation is shown by the navigation controller. I was just showing how I configure the navigation bar, in case they're related.

Comment: ok we do  the trick

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @beshio I have something similar. viewWillAppear() of the single controller that wants the bar unhides it, while viewWillAppear() of the other controllers hide it. That works fine. The issue isn't that the bar appears or disappears at the wrong time, it's that the animation causes the buttons to animate weirdly.

Comment: pardon , can you please explain clearly

Comment: I was saying that I did not show you the animation code because it's not my code. It's iOS code that shows and hides the navigation bar. The only thing I can show you is the code that configures the navigation bar.

Comment: My problem was NOT that the bar was displayed incorrectly, but the animation got weird. Bar display itself for my case was perfect. If you are passing the "animated" argument passed at viewWillApear() to setNa‌​vigationBarHidden(), then your issue is not the same as mine. Pls disregard my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be to do the following in the init of the UIPageViewController subclass:

```
automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

I don't know why it works, but it does.

I was earlier doing this in the child view controller (that represents a single page of the page view controller), but that wasn't working.